# Merge Two Corpus in R

Tags: r, merge, corpus

I am trying to combine two corpus by using R. but it gives me an error, 
" Error: could not find function "positiveCorpus.merge_with" . I am new to R Programming. can you please help me to solve this error.

code:

```
createCorpus <- function(dirPath) {
 a  <-Corpus(DirSource(dirPath), readerControl = list(language="en"))
a <- tm_map(a, removeNumbers)
  a <- tm_map(a, removePunctuation)
  a <- tm_map(a , stripWhitespace)
  a <- tm_map(a, tolower)
  a <- tm_map(a, removeWords, c("movie","films","film", stopwords("english")))
return(a)
}
positiveCorpus <- createCorpus("D:/txt1/pos")
negCorpus <- createCorpus("D:/txt2/neg")
library(itertools)
mergeCorpus=positiveCorpus.merge_with(negCorpus)
```

Comment: It means that the function `positiveCorpus.merge_with(negCorpus)` is not defined. Did you try to define that function yourself? Or is it part of a package?

Comment: Actually I dont know how to merge two corpus in R. I got one code from net                                                                                                      dict1 = corpora.Dictionary.Load("d1.dict")
dict2 = corpora.Dictionary.Load("d2.dict")
dict2_to_dict1=dict1.merge_with(dict2)

corp1=corpora.MmCorpus("d1.mm")
corp2=corpora.MmCorpus("d2.mm")

merged_corpus= itertools.chain(corp1,dict2_to_dict1[corp2])                     but its not working....